# Git init issue showing "Error: Could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unabailable (-1)

Tags: git, dll, cygwin, git-bash, rebase

The error appeared after installation. Cygwin64 Terminal shows "Error: Could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1)...DDL rebasing may be required; see 'rebaseall / rebase --help'. I also get a similar error when I open VS Code > new terminal > gitbash.

[image: error code 1 and 2]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Git (6 times), turned off force randomization for images (mandatory ASLR) and randomize memory allocations (bottom-up ASLR) for expr.exe, grep.exe, rm.exe, sh.exe, uname.exe. I've tried changing the Git folder location but nothing seems to work. Could someone please help?

I feel like I'm losing my mind and I only want to continue working through this online tutorial...and I feel like it's a simple fix and I'm overcomplicating things... so any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The error message suggested rebasing, have tried it?

Comment: See [this superuser question for instance](https://superuser.com/questions/231590/running-rebaseall-on-cygwin). This is not a Git issue, it's some kind of Cygwin/Windows issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix.

1. Go to you Windows Defender Security Center settings
2. Click on App & Browser Control
3. At the bottom click on the "Exploit Protection Settings" link
4. Go to "Program Settings" and click on the "Add program to customize" -> "Choose exact file path"
5. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe" and add it
6. Override and turn off the following:
   Mandatory ASLR
   Randomize memory allocations (Bottom-up ASLR)
7. Click "Apply" and now everything should work fine.